# "value cannot be null parameter" Exception in windows phone 7 asynchronous call

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous

I am a Windows Phone developer. I am just beginning to work with asynchronous calls. Here is my code to get some meta data. Some points about it:

- I had called getmetadata() inside another method callback
- I expect `cskeys` to have 5 values
- I checked I am getting jsessionid
- I checked I am getting sessioncookie

There are two functions, `GetMetaData` and `GetFolder_MetadataCallback`:

```
  private void GetMetadata()
    {
       try
        {
            foreach (string folderpath in CSKeys) 
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderpath))
                {
                    HttpWebRequest FolderMetadataRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(URL + folderpath));
                    FolderMetadataRequest.Method = DisplayMessage.HeadMethod;
                    FolderMetadataRequest.Headers[DisplayMessage.Header_Authorization] = Authentication_Parameters[DisplayMessage.Username] + DisplayMessage.Colon +
                                                                                         Authentication_Parameters[DisplayMessage.JSessionID]; 
                    FolderMetadataRequest.Headers[DisplayMessage.Header_Cookie] = Authentication_Parameters[DisplayMessage.SessionCookie];

                    FolderMetadataRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetFolder_MetadataCallback), FolderMetadataRequest);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    private void GetFolder_MetadataCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest FolderReq = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse FolderResponse = (HttpWebResponse)FolderReq.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
            if (FolderResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                System.Net.WebHeaderCollection folderMedataCollection = FolderResponse.Headers;
                Dictionary<string, string> FolderMetadata_Header = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                FolderMetadata_Header.Add(DisplayMessage.UniqueID_Key, folderMedataCollection[DisplayMessage.UniqueID_Value]);
                FolderMetadata_Header.Add(DisplayMessage.Actual_Name_Key, folderMedataCollection[DisplayMessage.Actual_Name_Value]);
                FolderMetadata_Header.Add(DisplayMessage.Display_Name_Key, folderMedataCollection[DisplayMessage.Display_Name_Value]);
                FolderMetadata_KeyValues.Add(FolderPath, FolderMetadata_Header);
            }
            app.Storage_Parameters.Add(DisplayMessage.Metadadata_StorageKey, FolderMetadata_KeyValues);
}
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

For the first,second and third `keyvalue(CSKey)` I am getting the response. I am getting all the values and it is added to the `FolderMetadata_Keyvalues` also. Sometimes For the fourth and fifth key(CSKey) I get a `Value cannot be null parameter` exception. Why?

Comment: I don't see how you're specifying that `CSKeys` should have 5 elements. Where exactly do you get the exception? What is the line of code where it occurs?

Comment: i will get the values from another method... i checked CSKey values also it is having 5 values... If i post the code it will be disturbing on seeing page of code so i left..

Comment: still, where is the exception occurring?

Comment: for the first key it is going to callback method iam getting response and iam getting responsevalue added to my dictionary which i defined. for the second occurs the same... while coming to the third value the process for first and second value is not happening... sometimes it is not coming to the callback method, loop gets completed and the exception occurs..

Comment: In simple how i can make a asynchronous call for each value in foreach?

Comment: 1. You have try catch blocks in both the methods. So, in which method you are getting exception ? 
2. Which line of your code is causing the exception ?
3. When exception occured what is the folderpath value ?
Answer the above questions. Also, I suggest you to use the break points to track the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found the reason for my exception even though iam getting all the values. Iam making request for each value in foreach. As it is asynchronous call the request of  each value is sent before the call completes.(i.e for the first value in foreach, request is sent to the callback, before it completes the second value request is sent to the callback function).because of this process the exception occurs.

The solution is that for foreach statement in asynchronous call either wait method has to be handle'd till callback completes the first value request or less the request of second value has to be sent after the response of first value in callback function.